# How to correctly use Apollo GraphQL on iOS with background session configuration?

Tags: ios, swift, graphql, apollo, apollo-ios

I use [Apollo iOS](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-ios) 0.8 with Xcode 9.3, Swift 4.1 and iOS 11, and initialise Apollo client instance like this:

```
import Apollo

// ... unrelated code skipped

let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default

if let token = keychain.accessToken {
  // Add additional headers as needed
  configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = [
    "Authorization": "Bearer \(token)"
  ]
}

let graphqlEndpoint = URL("https://sample-server-url/graphql")!
let client = ApolloClient(networkTransport:
  HTTPNetworkTransport(url: graphqlEndpoint, configuration: configuration))
```

The application works well with all queries and mutations sent to the GraphQL server without a problem, except when the app is in background. As far as I know, with common `NSURLSession` instance it can be easily solved by switching session configuration to `URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "your-session-id")`.

But when I replace the line

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
```

with

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "your-session-id")
```

the app starts crashing with this error: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Completion handler blocks are not supported in background sessions. Use a delegate instead.'`

What's the best way to resolve this error when using Apollo GraphQL or is there any other way to communicate with a GraphQL server in background?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apollo iOS provides a public `NetworkTransport` protocol that allows overriding all networking interactions. An implementation can be provided as an argument to `ApolloClient(networkTransport: NetworkTransport)` initialiser.

Suppose you have a `NetworkTransport` implementation that wraps `URLSession` implementation with background session configuration:

```
class BackgroundTransport: NetworkTransport {
    public func send<Operation>(operation: Operation,
    completionHandler: @escaping (GraphQLResponse<Operation>?, Error?) -> Void)
    -> Cancellable where Operation: GraphQLOperation {
    // ...
    }
}
```

Then you can initialise `ApolloClient` this way:

```
let graphqlEndpoint = URL("https://sample-server-url/graphql")!
let client = ApolloClient(networkTransport: BackgroundTransport(url: u))
```

`BackgroundTransport` implementation can be as custom as needed, including using `URLSession` delegate instead of completion handler blocks, as required for background session configuration.

If you use [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/) in your app, you can also use [ApolloAlamofire](https://github.com/maxdesiatov/ApolloAlamofire) library that provides an implementation of `NetworkTransport` with support for background `URLSession` configuration and a few more features.